# Page Redirection in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am facing problem with change permalink actually I am using `Redirection plugin` you can see this plugin from here.

```
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/
```

I have installed this plugin and activate.After that I want to change the url of page having page id 5 .Url is provided for each page by client so I need this

```
  for example:page_id=5 is about us page and I want to change this as shown in target URL

  Source URL:http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/?page_id=5
  Target URL:http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/About.php
```

After that I clicked `Add Redirection` But when I click About us tab from header navigation it navigate to `About.php` but show this message give below.

```
 You have entered the wrong url/ page name. Click here for continueCLICK HERE
```

Please help me its very urgent.Please provide me any help regard this how this plugin will work in right way as I want

Thanks

Comment: For specific Wordpress questions, you might try asking here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok,Thank for reply I think Its very helpful for me further.From here I can learn alot of wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Thats a 404 Not Found Error.
Please, make sure that the page actually exists on your WordPress blog.

However, since the WordPress' 404 page is not being shown, either your theme does not support 404 page OR something is wrong in the way Redirection plugin is setup.

**Also, what you want can be simply achieved and does not require Redirection plugin.**

Go to the Permalinks Settings page (should be, but can be different: `http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`)

Use the following `Custom Structure` under `Common Settings`: `/%category%/%postname%.php`

Comment: Thanks for reply .Ya you are right I can achive this using `/%category%/%postname%.php` but before .php extension its take url acoording to page title.For example if I use this `/%category%/%postname%.php` then its make my url something like this about-us.php because my Page title `About Us`.But I dont want about us in url .I exactly want `About.php`

Comment: Yes Sir its 404 Not Found Error. But why its goes to 404 not found.This page exist with this id `http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/?page_id=5`

Comment: I just want to Redirect this page to `Target URL:http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/About.php` using Redirection plugin

Comment: @shalu: just change the post-slug (when editing the post) to about and you will be able to access the url as: `http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/about.php`. The reason I am not suggesting you Redirection plugin is that it requires some settings to be configured depending on what you wanna achieve and can sometimes be malfunctioned with .htaccess settings etc on your blog. Using the above permalink and a custom slug would be the neatest and most efficient way to do what you want.

Comment: I am using `Custom Structure:/%category%/%postname%.php` from permalink setting.When I am trying to edit this premalink to  'About' then after click of `save` it display this url `http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/about-2 ` you can check this link

Comment: Its not add .php extension after the url and also I dont want `about.php`.I exactly want `About.php`.Reason behind exactly this is its current site already running and  `SEO` working for the previous one site so the client want the same url as in previous website.I hope u understand what the actual requirement.

Comment: Hey Shalu, try: `Source URL:/Dev/?page_id=5` and `Target URL:/Dev/About.php` in Redirection plugin. Also, keep in mind that, if your blog is in `Dev` sub-directory, you will need to add some specific .htaccess rules to it, as far as I remember, but would not really be able to help with the specific .htaccess rules. I am sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

@shalu: Edit the page and under the title area you should see the post `slug`; change this to `About`. The post `slug` and post `title` can be completely different from each other. Then you should be able to use WordPress' built-in *Permalink Settings* with the *Custom Structure*: `/%postname%.php`

**Update**

I think the only way you might be able to achieve what you want is to manually add your custom entries to the WordPress `.htaccess` file. Example of how to make WordPress ignore certain rules here: http://www.ideashower.com/learned/override-wordpress-htaccess-with-custom-rewrite-rules/

Comment: When I edit this slug to About its not be changed.Now the url display here is this `http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/about-us`

Comment: If you're using the latest version of WordPress, then you need to click on the `edit` button next to the slug, make the change, click on the `ok` button and then click the `update` button to make the change permanent. You should see `Page updated. View page` with `View page` containing `/About.php`.

Comment: Ya I am doing the same but no progess its editable but not the exactly as I want.for page having title About us  If I click edit and enter `ABC` the press ok it shows the permalink `http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/abc' and then I click update the about us page redirect to  `http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/abc`.`1.)Noticable thing` is that I have entered caps ABC but after click of ok button its show in small letters.`2.)thing its not showing .php after the url

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need the custom redirection plugin. If you deactivate the plugin, and then go to the permalinks settings, and switch on nicer URLs, you can name every post/page by editing the slug. Both the ID based URL and name based URLs will work.

This won't give you .php endings, but a more friendly /page/name/ type URL based upon categories, post dates or page parents.

Answer (score 0):

Three things I noticed:

1. You linked to http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/About.php not **http://www.lifecellskin.us/About.php**  (no DV)
2. You linked directly to the About.php (sometimes this can cause problems with other plugins)
3. Some themes don't like capital letters.